# Should modules be in source code management?

Tags: version-control

I am new to Drupal and I am using Drupal 7.61.

Should the Drupal modules folder be git ignored or included in the source code management for best practices and continuous integration sake?

Comment: This article should give you a better idea: https://www.morpht.com/blog/drupal-and-composer-part-2-managing-drupal-8-site-composer (disclaimer: I'm the author of that article)

Comment: It depends... It's a rather opinion-based thing. And wether you manage your project via Composer for example.

Answer (score 2):

As Jaypan and leymannx say in the comments above, if you use Composer to manage dependencies, you can just include `composer.json` and `composer.lock` in your version control repository. Then you can use Composer to rebuild your project when you deploy. This has the advantage of keeping all third party code out of your repo.

https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/using-composer/using-composer-to-manage-drupal-site-dependencies

The documentation linked above shows how to use Composer to install Drupal core, contrib modules, and even patches and libraries.

This approach is the emerging standard. But it has its pros and cons. Here are some Drupal and Composer "gotchas" to look out for:

https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2017/composer-and-drupal-are-still-strange-bedfellows

If you *don't* use Composer, it's probably a good idea to keep core, contrib, patches and libraries in version control.

Answer (score -2):

For Drupal, it is best practice to add settings.php, public, and private files to the `.gitignore` file like as following:

```
# Ignore configuration files that may contain sensitive information.
sites/*/settings*.php

# Ignore paths that contain user-generated content.
sites/*/files
sites/*/private
```

You can learn more about source code management by using git from here:
https://www.drupal.org/node/803746

Comment: I didn't -1 but this is an extremely minimalistic opinion. If you'd like to drop a proper answer to this question, please explain how you come to your conclusion and a least name some possible alternatives.

Comment: It doesn’t even discuss modules, or take into account projects using Drush Make or similar or build servers.